# Create the look filter for custom field in lighting

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, filters

I have created the custom case component for the community and I have to apply the lookup criteria to create a filter to limit the records available to users.

In my salesforce org (standard case object): This criteria is working fine 
[image]

But In my the custom case component I have tried with this filter with these criteria but still, it is not working in my custom component.

```
<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12">
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="horizontal-small">
        <p class="slds-p-top_medium">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Property_Staff_Name__c" required="true" aura:id="Property_Staff_Name__c" />
        </p>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</div>
```

> filter = "{column:'Property Staff Name:Property_Cont__c',
>   operator:'equals', value:'PropertyCase__c'}"

Comment: Are you wanting the Case Property Name to not be 'blank'? If so, you need to put `''` in the Value box to the right of that Field for this filter to work. That is likely the problem you're having with your filter.

Comment: No, I have to apply the filter in my custom code but this code is not working in my component